# Accessing two network with the help of vm

Tags: networking, virtual-machine

I have a LAN Connection as well as a wifi connection both have internet. Can i access internet  through LAN in VM which runs ubuntu and Wifi through the Host OS which runs windows. What settings should I choose on the VM?

Edit:
I am running
VMPlayer : 5.0.2
VM Os : Ubuntu 13.10
Host Os: Windows 7

Answer (score 0):

Go to edit your virtual machine settings and then under network adapter select configure adapters and select the one you want to use for your VM.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, but it requires a minimum of attention.

The reason is that, if you choose a NAT connection, you cannot be sure that communication from the VM will pass through your ethernet interface. Actually, since we shall be making the wifi the main network interface of your host, you are **sure** that the VM will be routed through the wifi interface.

A bridge adapter instead bridges the VM's interface with the ethernet connection, **by default**. You can see this [from this VMWare's man page](https://www.vmware.com/support/ws4/doc/network_configure_ws.html#1061905), where it is stated that:

> By default, the VMnet0 virtual network is set up in bridged mode and bridges to one of the active Ethernet adapters on the host computer.

On a Windows host, in VMWare, you could also bridge to a wifi interface, instead of an ethernet interface. The same page above shows how to reach the page depicted below:

[image]

If you **un**tick *Enable Automatic Bridge*, you can specify your host's wifi adapter, so that you can make absolutely sure the VM is routed throught the ethernet.

Start your VM at this point Now make sure  your wifi interface
connects to your gateway: display the routing table by issuing, on the host, the command

```
  route print -4
```

Make sure that your default gateway is on your wireless NIC, otherwise change it to be that on your wireless NIC (if you do not know how to do that, say so). You are now done.